# Message appearing on Form saying "(not shared) Switch account"

Tags: forms

Google Form message has appeared August 30 2021.
Message is "emailaddress@gmail.com (not shared) Switch account"
It appears just above the *Required message at the top of the form.
Data can still be entered into the form, but the message is off-putting for respondents.
Can this message be removed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.